# Storing document.write in a variable not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

The following program prints "Hello world" as expected

```
var print = function(t){
  document.write(t);
};

var printAlias = print;

printAlias("Hello world");
```

But when I use the same technique with document.write it does not work.

```
var write = document.write ;
write("Something);
```

Can anybody tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you've lost the context (the "`this` value") within the `write` method of `document`. You can invoke `write` with the [`call` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to get it back:

```
write.call(document, "Something");
```

In your first example you are simply wrapping the call to `document.write` in another function, but the call itself keeps the context because you invoke `write` as a method of `document`.

So you may as well stick with the usual or your wrapper function if it's shorter code you were aiming for! Or (thanks @Esailija) you could [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the context to `document` at the time you create your `write` variable:

```
var write  = document.write.bind(document);
```

Comment: He might as well `var write = document.write.bind( document )` since `write.call` is not supported in older IE anyway

Comment: @Esailija - Yeah true. I didn't know that it wasn't supported in older IE. Which version did that get fixed in?

Comment: Ok. So the write method uses "this" somewhere inside and expects "this" to be document.  Am I right?

Comment: @JamesAllardice I am not really sure, I just remember older IE not even defining `.call` on DOM functions

Comment: @Esailija - Yeah that rings a bell. I rarely use `.call` or `.apply` on DOM methods and need to support old IE. Thanks.